# OpenGL triangle not appearing

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, shader, c++14

Hello everyone im trying to learn openGL using shaders so i made a triangle that changes its color while it moves but for some reason the trigle does not appear in the window, just a black background , it doesn't crash or show any kind of error, i believe the libraries set up is ok since i've used them before.
Im using CLion on Ubuntu 16.04. Here is my code so hopefully you can check it out and give me a hand. Thanks!

```
#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>


int CurrentWidth = 800,
CurrentHeight = 600,
WindowHandle = 0;

GLuint
    VertexShaderId,
    FragmentShaderId,
    ProgramId;

GLuint s_vertexLoc, s_colorLoc , s_factorLoc;

GLfloat  runner = 0.0;

const GLchar* VertexShader =
    {
            "#version 150\n"
            "attribute vec3 in_vertex;"
            "attribute vec3 in_color;"

            "uniform float factor;"

            "varying vec3 intp_color;"

            "void main(void)"
            "{"
                "intp_color = in_color;"
                "gl_Position = vec4( in_vertex , 1.0 ) ;"
                "gl_Position.y += factor; "
            "}"

    };

//Telling every single pixel is going to be red
const GLchar* FragmentShader =
    {
            "#version 150\n"
            "uniform float factor;"
            "varying vec3 intp_color;"
            "void main(void){"
                "gl_FragColor = vec4( intp_color , 1.0) * factor;"
            "}"
    };


// for. dec.
void ResizeFunction(int, int);
void RenderFunction(void);
void IdleFunction(void);
void CreateShaders(void);



// set up an array for the geometry of the object
GLfloat Vertices[] = {
    -0.5f , -0.2f , 0.0f, // point A - x , y , z
    0.5f , -0.2f , 0.0f, // point B - x , y , z
    0.0f ,  0.8f , 0.0f  // point C - x , y , z
};

GLfloat Colors[] = {
    1.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f, // point A - x , y , z
    0.0f , 1.0f , 0.0f, // point B - x , y , z
    0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f  // point C - x , y , z
};


int main( int argc , char* argv[] )
{
glutInit( &argc , argv);

//Target version 3.1
glutInitContextVersion(3 , 1 );

glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE |     GLUT_RGBA );

WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow( "OpenGL - Shader example" );

glutReshapeFunc( ResizeFunction );
glutDisplayFunc( RenderFunction );
glutIdleFunc( IdleFunction );

/// init GLEW
GLenum GlewInitResult;
GlewInitResult = glewInit();

if (GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

/// Create our shaders
CreateShaders();

glutMainLoop();

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


void ResizeFunction(int Width, int Height)
{
CurrentWidth = Width;
CurrentHeight = Height;
glViewport( 0, 0, CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight );
glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
}

void RenderFunction(void)
{
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

//We enable the shader variable
glEnableVertexAttribArray( s_vertexLoc );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( s_colorLoc );

//How to send data to the variable:
//( Where to send the data , how its grouped , data type , dont normalize the data,
// there is no offset, you find it here)

glVertexAttribPointer( s_vertexLoc , 3 , GL_FLOAT , GL_FALSE , 0 , Vertices );
glVertexAttribPointer ( s_colorLoc , 3 , GL_FLOAT , GL_FALSE , 0 , Colors);

glUniform1f( s_factorLoc , runner );
runner += 0.01;
if(runner > 1.0f)
    runner = -1.0f;

glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES , 0 , 3 );

glDisableVertexAttribArray( s_vertexLoc );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( s_colorLoc );

glutSwapBuffers();
  }

void IdleFunction(void)
{
glutPostRedisplay();
}

//Error checking
void printLog(GLuint obj)
{
int infologLength = 0;
int maxLength;

if( glIsShader( obj ) )
    glGetShaderiv( obj , GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH , &maxLength );
else
    glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

char infoLog[1255];

if ( glIsShader(obj) )
    glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, maxLength, &infologLength, infoLog );
else
    glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, maxLength, &infologLength, infoLog );

if ( infologLength > 0 )
    printf( "\n Error detail: %s\n" , infoLog );
}


void CreateShaders(void)
{
GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

if( glCreateShader )
    printf(" ---- shader suppot ok ---");
else
{
    printf(" ---- no shader support ---");
    return ;
}

///The VERTEX shader is created (tell it what it is)
VertexShaderId = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
//(shader we want to set the source, how many are they, the source of the shader , )
glShaderSource( VertexShaderId , 1 , &VertexShader , nullptr );
//Compile the shader
glCompileShader( VertexShaderId );

//Error checking
printLog( VertexShaderId );


///The FRAGMENT shader is created (tell it what it is)
FragmentShaderId = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
//(shader we want to set the source, how many are they, the source of the shader , )
glShaderSource( FragmentShaderId , 1 , &FragmentShader , nullptr );
//Compile the shader
glCompileShader( FragmentShaderId );

//Error checking
printLog( FragmentShaderId );


///Program Object links both shaders
ProgramId = glCreateProgram();
//Attach the compiled shaders to the program
glAttachShader( ProgramId , VertexShaderId );
glAttachShader( ProgramId , FragmentShaderId );
//Links the shaders to the program
glLinkProgram( ProgramId );

//Error checking
printLog( ProgramId );

//Uses the program to render
glUseProgram( ProgramId );

//( check this program , for this variable and return it)
s_vertexLoc = glGetAttribLocation( ProgramId , "in_vertex" );
s_colorLoc = glGetAttribLocation( ProgramId , "in_color" );
s_factorLoc = glGetUniformLocation( ProgramId , "factor" );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues.

- First, using OpenGL 3.1 (GLSL 1.30) is discouraged. Try with at least
  3.2 (GLSL 1.50) and ask for that Core Profile in your glut initialization. Then replace "**attribute**" with "**in**" in your
  vertex shader and "**varying**" with "**in**" or "**out**" depending
  if this var is going to be used as an input or an output.
- Second. This

  //How to send data to the variable:
     //( Where to send the data , how its grouped , data type , dont normalize the data,
     // there is no offset, **you find it here**)

  glVertexAttribPointer( s_vertexLoc , 3 , GL_FLOAT , GL_FALSE , 0 , Vertices );
     glVertexAttribPointer ( s_colorLoc , 3 , GL_FLOAT , GL_FALSE , 0 , Colors);

  is not true. That last value is a *byte offset into the buffer object's data store*, **not** the data itself.
- Third: You need a buffer for your vertices coordinates. Use
  `glGenBuffers()`, `glBufferData()`, and `glBindBuffer()`

If I were in your case I'd follow some tutorial on "modern OpenGL". Search the web, there are a lot.